# moving script to external file

Tags: javascript

I'm really new in js. Not fill well with js at all yet. I search on stack and found similar problem but this sollutions not working for me.
I have code in index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".well"),
heights = [];
/* Getting an array with the heights */
[].forEach.call(elements, function (each) { 
heights[heights.length] = getComputedStyle(each, null).getPropertyValue("height"); 
});
/* Sorting the array to get the greatest value first */
heights.sort(function (a, b) { 
return parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a); 
});
/* Applying the greatest height to each element */ 
[].forEach.call(elements, function (each) { 
each.style.height = heights[0]; 
});
});
```

and now I want to move this to external file to use not only once.
so i create file: layout.js with code

```
function equalHeightClass(object) {
"use strict";
var
    elements = document.querySelectorAll(object),
    heights = [];

/* Getting an array with the heights */
[].forEach.call(elements, function (each) {
    heights[heights.length] = getComputedStyle(each, null).getPropertyValue("height");
});

/* Sorting the array to get the greatest value first */
heights.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a);
});

/* Applying the greatest height to each element */
[].forEach.call(elements, function (each) {
    each.style.height = heights[0];
});
}
```

and on index I place

```
<script src="js/layout.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        equalHeightClass(.btn);
        equalHeightClass(.well);
    });
</script>
```

but this not work, I try with quotes, without, still don't know where is error.

Comment: [How to debugg JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

Comment: What are `.btn` and `.well` supposed to be? You don't define them anywhere. Also is your **layout.js** file really in a "js" subfolder?

Comment: I am sure your developer console has the error message....

Answer (score 0):

For the record, in:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        equalHeightClass('.btn');
        equalHeightClass('.well');
    });
</script>
```

You will need quotes on the parameters, because in this case you will be using that value in querySelectorAll, which requires them.

Are you having any console errors showing in the debugger? In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

All is working, path is correct. 
I make typo error when call function. Now I learn to keep functions name siple.